# Typo3 and xdebug_start(); gives error in backend?

Tags: xdebug, typo3

I needed to debug a T3 installation with Xdebug and I used xdebug_start(); to break the application cursor and start a debugger session. When I ended the session and terminate my IDE Typo3 throws some error saying unknown command "xdebug_start()" or something in the BE and prints a heavy table with backtrace etc. T3 keeps working but is this normal? Do I have to remove all "xdebug_start();" commands in the file?
[image]

Comment: You really have the xdebug PHP extension installed?

Comment: So what about posting the output of the "some error" message?

Comment: It's a problem with Color TV and TV 1.5.5+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the URL parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 ? There are also extensions for Firefox and IIRC for Chrome, too, which enable you to easily switch on/off passing of this parameter. I prefer this way, as you don't have to modify your source code.

Comment: My question was about xdebug_start(). I use Firefox with xdebug extension and I've tried he URL parameter.